# django-auth-ldap - find if user belongs to a ldap group

Tags: python, django, django-auth-ldap

I am trying to configure ldap authentication for a django project. Where all users should be able to access the web services ( I achieved this ). I would like to make few people (part of ldap group) as admins. I need to verify if logged in user belongs to a ldap group.

I am not using Django default authentication backend and not planning to use as well.

Is there any simple way to find if user belongs to a particular ldap group ?

I tried to read and understand "https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/index.html" but it is at very high level and without examples.

Comment: do you have any your code ?

Answer (score 2):

My problem is solved.

```
settings.py:

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.mycompany.com"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "CN=%(user)s,OU=Employees,OU=mycompany Users,DC=dev,DC=mycompany,DC=com"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend']

# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("CN=%(user)s,OU=Employees,OU=mycompany Users,DC=dev,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=top)"  #updated objectClass=top, it was groupOfNames
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="CN") #added argument name_attr="CN"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenname",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {"home_directory": "homeDirectory"}
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "CN=activeGroup,OU=Standard,OU=mycompany Groups,DC=dev,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
    "is_staff": "CN=staffGroup,OU=Standard,OU=mycompany Groups,DC=dev,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
    "is_superuser": "CN=GROUPNAME,OU=AnwenderRollen,OU=Gruppen,ou=XXX,ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX"
}
### Added all below lines
# Use LDAP group membership to calculate group permissions.
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
# Cache group memberships for an hour to minimize LDAP traffic
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 1 #3600
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER = True

views.py:

def login_view(request):
    username = ""
    password = ""
    state = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('cec')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/homepage')
            print "user.is_active:", user.is_active
            print "user.is_staff:", user.is_staff
            print "user.is_superuser:", user.is_superuser
        else:
            state = "Invalid Credentials !!!" 
    return render(request,'testapp/loginpage.html',{'state':state})
```

Comment: I have tons of groups in AD, so it is not practical to replicate group into django app. I want to do individual mapping between AD group and django group. How to??